# Safe version of Google API .NET client after the discontinuation of JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch endpoints

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Concerning the [discontinuation of JSON-RPC and Global HTTP Batch endpoints](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html) on Google API in March 2019, which minimal version of Google API .NET client would it be safe to use if neither heterogenous batches nor manual RPC custom requests are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any recent version of any Google.Apis.* library is safe to use. These libraries don't use any batching or JSON-RPC "under the covers".

So long as you don't use heterogeneous batching yourself there won't be any problems.

Also see: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1178